# How to determine when HBase is ready after a start?

Tags: linux, bash, hbase

I want a software that depends on HBase, and must be started only after it's fully started and ready for business, but it seems like start-hbase.sh returns before this happens.

Is there any way to check/wait for HBase status?

I tried something like `echo "status" | hbase shell`, but it doesn't return while HBase is offline. I'd like to get a status code or text saying wheter it's ready or not.

Comment: can see status at  master:60010

Comment: Yes, in fact, this is what I'm using until a better answer show up. Parsing the web page looks way to hacky

Answer (score 0):

We check the following components:

1) checking `hbase/bin/hbase shell` for insert\list 'testtable':

```
echo "create 'testtable', {NAME=>'colfam'}" | hbase_home/bin/hbase shell
echo "list" | hbase_home/bin/hbase shell
```

2) `hbase/bin/hbase hbck | grep "INCONSISTENT"` return non-zero code (all hbase data are consistent).

It's enough to be sure hbase is ready, but I'm trying to find more easy way now.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the method where you try to create a table and keep trying until you can see the table was created, but I found it was unnecessarily slow for the case that I wanted to use hbase for (a number of unit tests) and so I wanted to make it faster. Having to open separate hbase shells to create the table, and list to check for existence was made slower by also having to open up shells afterwards to remove the table, so I've been working with a way to do it all in a single shell execution.

This script will attempt to create a table, but if it is unable to for any reason, it will immediately exit with a non-zero status due to `-n` which makes it a non-interactive session. It will continue until the create succeeds, which will be followed immediately by the clean up of the test table.

Would love some thoughts on this approach

```
echo "Waiting for HBase to be ready..."
isHBaseReady=1
while [ ${isHBaseReady} -ne 0 ]
do
  echo "Testing table creation..."
  echo -e "create 'testtable', 'cf'\ndisable 'testtable'\ndrop 'testtable'" | \
    /opt/hbase-$HBASE_VERSION/bin/hbase shell -n > /dev/null 2>&1 && isHBaseReady=$?
done
echo "HBase is operational"
```

Output:

```
Waiting for HBase to be ready...
Testing table creation...
Testing table creation...
HBase is operational
```